# How to set a UITableView Editing Mode from a swipe action?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, uiswipeactionsconfiguration

I need to turn on a tableView editing mode by clicking on one of its cells from swipe action "move":

Code for swipe action:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let move = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Переместить") { (action, view, completionHandler) in
        self.turnEditing()
        completionHandler(true)
    }
    move.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "CalmBlueColor")
    
    let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [move])
    return configuration
}
```

turnEditing() function:

```
   func turnEditing() {
       if tableView.isEditing {
           tableView.isEditing = false
       } else {
           tableView.isEditing = true
       }
    }
```

TableView Delegates:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
    return .none
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

When I press on the swipe actions it's just closes, without going to editing mode...
Here is the [GIF](https://cln.sh/ilEN9F)

Is it possible to go into editing mode from a swipe action or only from a barButtonItem + IBAction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some delay

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.75) {
  self.turnEditing()
}
```

BTW you could replace this

```
if tableView.isEditing {
  tableView.isEditing = false
} else {
  tableView.isEditing = true
}
```

With

```
tableView.isEditing.toggle()
```